# Notation Problem

Tags: notation

I'm reading a paper that uses the notation $[f]^+_-$ for a function f. Anyone know that this means?

More explicitly it appears as

$$ \frac{1}{{[U_0]}^+_-} \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}U_{0z}^2 \, \mathrm{d}z$$

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper if possible...

Comment: http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~masgat//PAPERS/CahnHilliard/CahEllNov.pdf

Comment: The notation is used in equation 4.10 on page 12.

Comment: I think it's explained after equation 1.8.